# SASS/SCSS: Bootstrap 5 Color functions not working well?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm using SASS and bootstrap the new version V5 as CSS Framework in some of my academic project in color part I stuck because the color functions not working as I expected I will explain where is the issue with images in next lines.

**first of all take a look to the current result :**

[image: Current Result]

as you can see in current result it's an alert component with orange in background and border color but the issue the text it should be white not black but in this example is black I want to change the color to be with dynamicly without using any custom css only editing the bootstrap color functions to be white color instead of black color.

**What I expected :**

[image: Expected result]

**Live Example on codepen**

[Live Example](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/YzGqOaJ)

**My FullCode :**

```
$_luminance-list: .0008 .001 .0011 .0013 .0015 .0017 .002 .0022 .0025 .0027 .003 .0033 .0037 .004 .0044 .0048 .0052 .0056 .006 .0065 .007 .0075 .008 .0086 .0091 .0097 .0103 .011 .0116 .0123 .013 .0137 .0144 .0152 .016 .0168 .0176 .0185 .0194 .0203 .0212 .0222 .0232 .0242 .0252 .0262 .0273 .0284 .0296 .0307 .0319 .0331 .0343 .0356 .0369 .0382 .0395 .0409 .0423 .0437 .0452 .0467 .0482 .0497 .0513 .0529 .0545 .0561 .0578 .0595 .0612 .063 .0648 .0666 .0685 .0704 .0723 .0742 .0762 .0782 .0802 .0823 .0844 .0865 .0887 .0908 .0931 .0953 .0976 .0999 .1022 .1046 .107 .1095 .1119 .1144 .117 .1195 .1221 .1248 .1274 .1301 .1329 .1356 .1384 .1413 .1441 .147 .15 .1529 .1559 .159 .162 .1651 .1683 .1714 .1746 .1779 .1812 .1845 .1878 .1912 .1946 .1981 .2016 .2051 .2086 .2122 .2159 .2195 .2232 .227 .2307 .2346 .2384 .2423 .2462 .2502 .2542 .2582 .2623 .2664 .2705 .2747 .2789 .2831 .2874 .2918 .2961 .3005 .305 .3095 .314 .3185 .3231 .3278 .3325 .3372 .3419 .3467 .3515 .3564 .3613 .3663 .3712 .3763 .3813 .3864 .3916 .3968 .402 .4072 .4125 .4179 .4233 .4287 .4342 .4397 .4452 .4508 .4564 .4621 .4678 .4735 .4793 .4851 .491 .4969 .5029 .5089 .5149 .521 .5271 .5333 .5395 .5457 .552 .5583 .5647 .5711 .5776 .5841 .5906 .5972 .6038 .6105 .6172 .624 .6308 .6376 .6445 .6514 .6584 .6654 .6724 .6795 .6867 .6939 .7011 .7084 .7157 .7231 .7305 .7379 .7454 .7529 .7605 .7682 .7758 .7835 .7913 .7991 .807 .8148 .8228 .8308 .8388 .8469 .855 .8632 .8714 .8796 .8879 .8963 .9047 .9131 .9216 .9301 .9387 .9473 .956 .9647 .9734 .9823 .9911 1;

@function color-contrast($background, $color-contrast-dark: $color-contrast-dark, $color-contrast-light: $color-contrast-light, $min-contrast-ratio: $min-contrast-ratio) {
  $foregrounds: $color-contrast-light, $color-contrast-dark, $white, $black;
  $max-ratio: 0;
  $max-ratio-color: null;

  @each $color in $foregrounds {
    $contrast-ratio: contrast-ratio($background, $color);
    @if $contrast-ratio > $min-contrast-ratio {
      @return $color;
    } @else if $contrast-ratio > $max-ratio {
      $max-ratio: $contrast-ratio;
      $max-ratio-color: $color;
    }
  }

  @warn "Found no color leading to #{$min-contrast-ratio}:1 contrast ratio against #{$background}...";

  @return $max-ratio-color;
}

@function contrast-ratio($background, $foreground: $color-contrast-light) {
  $l1: luminance($background);
  $l2: luminance(opaque($background, $foreground));

  @return if($l1 > $l2, ($l1 + .05) / ($l2 + .05), ($l2 + .05) / ($l1 + .05));
}

@function luminance($color) {
  $rgb: (
    "r": red($color),
    "g": green($color),
    "b": blue($color)
  );

  @each $name, $value in $rgb {
    $value: if($value / 255 < .03928, $value / 255 / 12.92, nth($_luminance-list, $value + 1));
    $rgb: map-merge($rgb, ($name: $value));
  }

  @return (map-get($rgb, "r") * .2126) + (map-get($rgb, "g") * .7152) + (map-get($rgb, "b") * .0722);
}

@function opaque($background, $foreground) {
  @return mix(rgba($foreground, 1), $background, opacity($foreground) * 100);
}

@function tint-color($color, $weight) {
  @return mix(white, $color, $weight);
}

@function shade-color($color, $weight) {
  @return mix(black, $color, $weight);
}

@function shift-color($color, $weight) {
  @return if($weight > 0, shade-color($color, $weight), tint-color($color, -$weight));
}

$white:          #ffffff       !default;
$black:          #000000       !default;

$min-contrast-ratio:   4.5                   !default;
$color-contrast-dark:  $black                !default;
$color-contrast-light: $white                !default;

$orange: #FFB74D !default;

$orange-50:  tint-color($orange, 90%)  !default;
$orange-100: tint-color($orange, 70%)  !default;
$orange-200: tint-color($orange, 50%)  !default;
$orange-300: tint-color($orange, 30%)  !default;
$orange-400: tint-color($orange, 10%)  !default;
$orange-500: $orange                   !default;
$orange-600: shade-color($orange, 20%) !default;
$orange-700: shade-color($orange, 40%) !default;
$orange-800: shade-color($orange, 60%) !default;
$orange-900: shade-color($orange, 80%) !default;

$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge(
    (
        "orange-50":   $orange-50,
        "orange-100":   $orange-100,
        "orange-200":   $orange-200,
        "orange-300":   $orange-300,
        "orange-400":   $orange-400,
        "orange-500":   $orange-500,
        "orange-600":   $orange-600,
        "orange-700":   $orange-700,
        "orange-800":   $orange-800,
        "orange-900":   $orange-900
    ),
    $theme-colors
);

@mixin alert-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $color: color-contrast($background)
) {
  color: $color;
  background-color: $background;
  border-color: $border;
}

@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .alert-#{$color} {
    @include alert-variant($value, $value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You will need to change the value of the `$min-contrast-ratio` variable to a lower value.

By default, Bootstrap v5 sets `4.5` as the default value as the recommend WCAG [ISO-9241-3] and [ANSI-HFES-100-1988], especially for elderly people or those with vision loss.
https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html

In your case, change the contrast ratio to a lower value but be aware that users with low vision or cognitive impairments may not be able to read your text.

Adding `$min-contrast-ratio: 2.5;` to your code will override the default making the text in your code white.

```
// Variables
$min-contrast-ratio: 2.5;

// Bootstrap
$_luminance-list: .0008 .001 .0011 .0013 .0015 .0017 .002 .0022 .0025 .0027 .003 .0033 .0037 .004 .0044 .0048 .0052 .0056 .006 .0065 .007 .0075 .008 .0086 .0091 .0097 .0103 .011 .0116 .0123 .013 .0137 .0144 .0152 .016 .0168 .0176 .0185 .0194 .0203 .0212 .0222 .0232 .0242 .0252 .0262 .0273 .0284 .0296 .0307 .0319 .0331 .0343 .0356 .0369 .0382 .0395 .0409 .0423 .0437 .0452 .0467 .0482 .0497 .0513 .0529 .0545 .0561 .0578 .0595 .0612 .063 .0648 .0666 .0685 .0704 .0723 .0742 .0762 .0782 .0802 .0823 .0844 .0865 .0887 .0908 .0931 .0953 .0976 .0999 .1022 .1046 .107 .1095 .1119 .1144 .117 .1195 .1221 .1248 .1274 .1301 .1329 .1356 .1384 .1413 .1441 .147 .15 .1529 .1559 .159 .162 .1651 .1683 .1714 .1746 .1779 .1812 .1845 .1878 .1912 .1946 .1981 .2016 .2051 .2086 .2122 .2159 .2195 .2232 .227 .2307 .2346 .2384 .2423 .2462 .2502 .2542 .2582 .2623 .2664 .2705 .2747 .2789 .2831 .2874 .2918 .2961 .3005 .305 .3095 .314 .3185 .3231 .3278 .3325 .3372 .3419 .3467 .3515 .3564 .3613 .3663 .3712 .3763 .3813 .3864 .3916 .3968 .402 .4072 .4125 .4179 .4233 .4287 .4342 .4397 .4452 .4508 .4564 .4621 .4678 .4735 .4793 .4851 .491 .4969 .5029 .5089 .5149 .521 .5271 .5333 .5395 .5457 .552 .5583 .5647 .5711 .5776 .5841 .5906 .5972 .6038 .6105 .6172 .624 .6308 .6376 .6445 .6514 .6584 .6654 .6724 .6795 .6867 .6939 .7011 .7084 .7157 .7231 .7305 .7379 .7454 .7529 .7605 .7682 .7758 .7835 .7913 .7991 .807 .8148 .8228 .8308 .8388 .8469 .855 .8632 .8714 .8796 .8879 .8963 .9047 .9131 .9216 .9301 .9387 .9473 .956 .9647 .9734 .9823 .9911 1;

@function color-contrast($background, $color-contrast-dark: $color-contrast-dark, $color-contrast-light: $color-contrast-light, $min-contrast-ratio: $min-contrast-ratio) {
  $foregrounds: $color-contrast-light, $color-contrast-dark, $white, $black;
  $max-ratio: 0;
  $max-ratio-color: null;

  @each $color in $foregrounds {
    $contrast-ratio: contrast-ratio($background, $color);
    @if $contrast-ratio > $min-contrast-ratio {
      @return $color;
    } @else if $contrast-ratio > $max-ratio {
      $max-ratio: $contrast-ratio;
      $max-ratio-color: $color;
    }
  }

  @warn "Found no color leading to #{$min-contrast-ratio}:1 contrast ratio against #{$background}...";

  @return $max-ratio-color;
}

@function contrast-ratio($background, $foreground: $color-contrast-light) {
  $l1: luminance($background);
  $l2: luminance(opaque($background, $foreground));

  @return if($l1 > $l2, ($l1 + .05) / ($l2 + .05), ($l2 + .05) / ($l1 + .05));
}

@function luminance($color) {
  $rgb: (
    "r": red($color),
    "g": green($color),
    "b": blue($color)
  );

  @each $name, $value in $rgb {
    $value: if($value / 255 < .03928, $value / 255 / 12.92, nth($_luminance-list, $value + 1));
    $rgb: map-merge($rgb, ($name: $value));
  }

  @return (map-get($rgb, "r") * .2126) + (map-get($rgb, "g") * .7152) + (map-get($rgb, "b") * .0722);
}

@function opaque($background, $foreground) {
  @return mix(rgba($foreground, 1), $background, opacity($foreground) * 100);
}

@function tint-color($color, $weight) {
  @return mix(white, $color, $weight);
}

@function shade-color($color, $weight) {
  @return mix(black, $color, $weight);
}

@function shift-color($color, $weight) {
  @return if($weight > 0, shade-color($color, $weight), tint-color($color, -$weight));
}

$white:          #ffffff       !default;
$black:          #000000       !default;

$min-contrast-ratio:   4.5                   !default;
$color-contrast-dark:  $black                !default;
$color-contrast-light: $white                !default;

$orange: #fd7e14 !default;

$orange-50:  tint-color($orange, 90%)  !default;
$orange-100: tint-color($orange, 70%)  !default;
$orange-200: tint-color($orange, 50%)  !default;
$orange-300: tint-color($orange, 30%)  !default;
$orange-400: tint-color($orange, 10%)  !default;
$orange-500: $orange                   !default;
$orange-600: shade-color($orange, 20%) !default;
$orange-700: shade-color($orange, 40%) !default;
$orange-800: shade-color($orange, 60%) !default;
$orange-900: shade-color($orange, 80%) !default;

$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge(
    (
        "orange":   $orange
    ),
    $theme-colors
);

@mixin alert-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $color: color-contrast($background)
) {
  color: $color;
  background-color: $background;
  border-color: $border;
}

@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .alert-#{$color} {
    @include alert-variant($value, $value);
    padding: 15px 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you may add the extra parameters to the `color-contrast` function if you don't want to affect the minimum contrast ratio directly or globally.

```
@mixin alert-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $color: color-contrast(
        $background,
        $color-contrast-dark, // Black text
        $color-contrast-light, // White text
        2.5 // minimum contrast ratio
  )
) {
  color: $color;
  background-color: $background;
  border-color: $border;
}
```

Comment: the acceptable values for WCAG 2.0 are 3, 4.5 and 7, which is what bootstrap uses for `min-contrast-ratio`.

Comment: @kjdion84 that's right, however, bootstrap only sets 4.5 as only 1 value can be set at a time for `min-contrast-ratio` yet you can change this to 3 or 7 if needed or make custom code for it or simply use `text-white`. In my example, setting it to 2.5 is the maximum value to force the text to be white based on the OP's background colour which is less than 3 (but this will affect every other colour too). This is not good for users with low vision or cognitive impairments and could potentially land you with a "Web Accessibility Lawsuit" if anyone makes a complaint.

Comment: Setting the `$min-contrast-ratio: 3;` was all I needed to get rid of the warnings in the browser.  Use 3 based on @kjdion84'a suggestion